# Azure devOps deployment release setup

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

If the connection string is setup as a secret variable in the release pipeline.

Is there any way or any one to view the secret variable?  If yes, how could we do it?

Comment: Sure. You could reverse the secret and print it to console. Or base 64 encode it. Or ROT13 encode it. Basically, any reversible transformation.

Comment: Sometimes to access secret value I am using qetza.replacetokens extension to write secret to a file on my self-hosted agent and then I just access it directly from the file.

Comment: @DanielMann Could you explain it more detail step by step?  I am new to dev.azure.com.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I write a powershell demo in the YAML file for you(Based on Daniel's idea.), please notice on the pipeline you will be unable to output the value because all of the same value will be captured by the pipeline and all of them will be covered by "***".

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host $(not_secure)
      Write-Host $(secure)
      
      #convert string to based64 string:
      
      $secret = "$(secure)"
      
      $secret = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($secret))
      
      Write-Host $secret

      Write-Host "value2" #Whenever the pipeline capture the same value of the secured secret, the pipeline will output '***'. So doing any tricks inside the pipeline can't make the pipeline output this value
```

> **Whenever the pipeline capture the same value of the secured secret,**
> **the pipeline will output `'***'`. So doing any tricks inside the**
> **pipeline can't make the pipeline output this value.**

My pipeline output:

[image]

My variables:

[image]

***get_secret_of_pipeline.ps1***(run this on your machine.)

```
$secret = "dmFsdWUy"

$secret = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($secret))

Write-Host $secret
```

Successfully get the value of secret:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for proving Azure DevOps secret values are not secure, but should probably follow that up with some further guidance like "use environment variables" or "use azure key vault" or this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash

Comment: Bowman, thank you for your post.  For some reason, I could not see the image you posted.  But it is great information.  I had ever seen that those secret field could show the value by clicking on the lock.   Could you tell me what the setting could disable displaying the real value and which role (only project collection admin?) will be able to decrypt the secret value?

Comment: @AdamVincent Great point for azure key vault. could you tell me who have access to azure key vault?  Will project collection administrator still could see it?

Comment: @Diane KeyVault is a separate Azure service with no relationship to Azure DevOps. You can integrate the two platforms. If you have specific questions about keyvault, feel free to ask a new question *after* reviewing the documentation and experimenting a bit.